# error in SQL syntax for LEFT JOIN statement in Android SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, left-join

```
  public ArrayList<String> getCitiesFromCountry(int countryCode){

     ArrayList<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 

     Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + COUNTRY_TABLE +
     " LEFT JOIN " + CITY_TABLE + " ON " + COUNTRY_TABLE + "." + _ID + " = " +
     CITY_TABLE + "." +  _ID2 + " WHERE " + COUNTRY_TABLE + "." + _ID + " = ?",
     new String{"1"});

     if (cursor != null){

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        cityNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CITY_NAME)));                   
     }
  }
  return cityNames;
  }
```

database constants

```
  public static final String WORLD_DATABASE = "world_database";
  public static final String COUNTRY_TABLE = "country_table";
  public static final String CITY_TABLE = "city_table";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  public static final String _ID = "_id";
  public static final String _ID2 = "_id2";
  public static final String COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";
  public static final String CITY_NAME = "city_name";
```

EDIT:  because of the compile error for syntax in the SQL statement, i can't run this so that is why there is no logcat stacktrace.

Comment: put your logcat here..

Comment: can not run it to get a logcat as there is compile error for the SQL statement,  i still can't figure out what is wrong with the syntax, i will add this to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + COUNTRY_TABLE +
     " LEFT JOIN " + CITY_TABLE + " ON " + COUNTRY_TABLE + "." + _ID + " = " +
     CITY_TABLE + "." +  _ID2 + " WHERE " + COUNTRY_TABLE + "." + _ID + " = ?",
     new String[]{"1"});
```

rawquery second paramter is an array

```
rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
```